# Download only specific part of Tensorflow Library

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I have a Deep Learning Code for Object Detection. What I did is that I ran the code on Google Colab and then Exported the model to use it locally. Now to run the model I have to again install whole Tensorflow package which is quite heavy for my system. 
I want to ask if there is a way to download and run only specific parts of Tensorflow Library?
I am using Tensorflow at only 2 places in my code and I have to install whole Tensorflow library for it.

- This is where I am loading the model.

  `detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load(PATH_TO_SAVED_MODEL)`
- This is where I am using Tensorflow 2nd time.

  `input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_rgb)`

These are the only 2 functions required to me from the Tensorflow Library and not the whole library... Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not entirely sure on the library as a whole, there is a Lite version of Tensorflow (I guess they realised 430MB is a bit much too).

Information regarding this can be found here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/

A guide here seems to detail how to pick and choose parts of the Lite library and although not used myself, I should expect some degree of compatibility between the two...

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/reduce_binary_size